# Variable size messages

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

I'm trying to create a packet in scapy, but I want the last field to be optional.

I have tried working with the `guess_payload_class()` putting it under the myMessage with no luck.

```py
msg1 = myMessage(TimeStamp=timestamp, SomeId1=2, SomeId2=3, SomeInt=20, SomeValue1=22, SomeValue2=18)

msg2 = myMessage(TimeStamp=timestamp, SomeId1=2, SomeId2=3, SomeInt=20, SomeValue1=22)


class myMessage(packet):
  fields_desc = [SccMsgs.ShortField("Length", 25),
                 SccMsgs.IntField("TimeStamp", None),
                 SccMsgs.ShortField("SomeId1", None),
                 SccMsgs.ShortField("SomeId2", None),
                 SccMsgs.IntField("SomeInt", None),
                 SccMsgs.ShortField("SomeValue1", None),
                 SccMsgs.ShortField("SommeValue2", None)]
```

I would like `msg2` to have a value 2 bytes smaller than `msg1`. But `msg2` is defaulting `SomeValue2` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `ConditionalField` ?
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_dissect.html?highlight=ConditionalField#special
That makes things optional.

Otherwise as you said, create a second layer and bind it to `myMessage` with `bind_layers`